# Serial.print / sprintf causes program crash

Tags: serial, arduino-leonardo

The following code

```
  int i;
  char msg[16]; // Serial data.

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("===============");

  sprintf(msg, "Sequence:  %4d", runNum);
  Serial.println(msg);

  Serial.print("LED colour: ");
  Serial.println(colours[colour]);

  Serial.print("Max mA:      ");
  Serial.println(mAmax);

  Serial.println("  mA    mV");
  for (i = 1; i <= mAmax; i++) {
    sprintf(msg, "%4d", i);          // <--- Line 1.
    Serial.print(msg);               // <--- Line 2.
    sprintf(msg, "%6d", i * 3);
    Serial.println(msg);
    delay(50);
  }
```

crashes after the first pass as shown below:

```
===============
Sequence:     1
LED colour: red
Max mA:      30
  mA    mV
   1     3
```

If I comment out "Line 1" and "Line 2" the loop runs correctly.

I suspect that something odd happens with either the two `sprintf` calls or the `Serial.print` / `Serial.println` calls in quick succession.

Can anyone spot an error or know of an issue that I've missed?

Development environment: create.arduino.cc

Comment: Not from that snippet, no. You need to show your full code, or a version of the code that at least compiles and demonstrates the problem. As it stands we cannot know what is happening because we don't know what your code is doing. What are your variable types? What values do they contain? What else is going on with your code that could have a bearing on it?

Comment: Please add the declaration of `msg`. The string buffer might be too small.

Comment: I forgot about the declaration. I've added that. I've also stripped down my code to the snippet above plus the setup, etc., and it works. Darn! More digging. I'll update later when I have more info.

Comment: %4d does not limit the maximum size. When the number is 20000 the whole 20000 is printed and your buffer will overflow. You assume that the loop runs correctly when those two lines are commented out. I doubt that. Data on stack that is overwritten or ram problems or heap overflow is not always detected. We still need a full working sketch that shows the problem.

Comment: avr-libc does have `snprintf()`, or you could check the value for limits before sprintfing it.

Comment: Where does `runNum` come from?

Comment: Please show your full code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hold off for a bit, thanks, guys. I've got the code working now but I'm struggling to find what the original problem was. The stripped down version ran fine. More later and I'll post my findings.